# How do I check why SSO causes cache-related problem?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, single-sign-on

When I login using SSO, change something on a page, submit request, changes are NOT applied on **first try**. If I redo it, it works.

If I login using SSO, I type my credentials on site B and get logged in on site A. This changes are not applied on site A only on first try.

If I log out of Site A, log in using SSO again(Don't need to retype my credentials because I am already logged in on Site B), everything works fine.

I thought it was cache problem.
I have tried disabling cache like this :

Added this in aspx.cs

```
 [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
```

and in aspx :

```
<%@ OutputCache NoStore="True" Duration="1" VaryByParam='*' Location="None" %>
```

in js file :

```
 $.ajax({
        cache: false
        //rest of ajax that gets data from back-end
    });
```

I added some logging and when something goes wrong is because data given from front to back is incorrect.
This is how it looks :

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HdnSelectedMenuIds" runat="server" />
```

on button save, I have this in aspx :

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="inputButton"
                OnClientClick="javascript:return GetNodeValue();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

There is corresponding function in js file.

```
function GetNodeValue() {
    var checkedMenuIds = [];
    var treeView = $("#treeviewTab").data("kendoTreeView");
    var extTreeView = $("#treeviewExternal").data("kendoTreeView");
    GetNodeId(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedMenuIds);
    GetNodeId(extTreeView.dataSource.view(), checkedMenuIds);
    $(myControls.HdnSelectedMenuIds).val(checkedMenuIds);
}
```

When something goes wrong, HdnSelectedMenuIds has wrong value.

I have no idea what happens. What should I try?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and WebForms in 2021?

Comment: What "changes" are you referring to and what makes you think SSO is involved? Also, **exactly** what SSO scheme are you using? (Windows Integrated (NTLM, Kerberos)), OAuth, OIDC, SAML?

Comment: `OnClientClick="javascript:return GetNodeValue();"` <-- this is incorrect because `GetNodeValue()` doesn't actually return anything (so it actually returns `undefined`), and returning a "falsy" value in an `onclick` inline function is equivalent to calling `event.stopPropagation()`. This is probably what the problem is.

Comment: I didn't choose to use WebForms and jQuery. It's an old project :) 
By changes I mean that when I enter the page, I have list of items with value of "on/off". 
If I change something from on to off, click submit(btn_Save), postback happens, page reloads and changes are not done - item is still set to ON. It only happens when I login for the first time using SSO; Only fails once - when something is not changed and I try again, it works without re-login. You made an interesting point regarding OnClientClick, I will try it

Comment: @Dai if I type return true in GetNodeValue(), will it work?

Comment: Just change it to `OnClientClick="GetNodeValue();"`, you don't need to change the body of `GetNodeValue()`.

Comment: @Dai I changed it. Unfortunately, in order to test it, I need to deploy this code. Because I can not login using SSO locally (that's why problem doesn't occur locally). Before I deploy it, could you please explain how are SSO and event.StopPropagation() connected? It doesn't work on first try if I'm logged in using SSO